# Short COMException question

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto

Hey guys, heres a short one :

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors[Inspect].Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
```

Throws a Type Mismatch 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH) error.

Close is expecting an OlInspectorClose alright, so I don't know why there is a type mismatch.

EDIT : More code for clarity!

```
public void Inspectors_Kill(Inspector Inspect)
    {
        Global.InspectorWrappers[Inspect].CustomTaskPane.Dispose();           
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors[Inspect].Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
        Global.InspectorWrappers.Remove(Inspect);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know that component, but is that enumeration supported by the dispatch interface?

Comment: That's for a MailItem, I'm trying to close an Inspector in the above code. This is probably the page for that, but it doesn't explain why I get a type mismatch : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869503.aspx

Comment: It could the be the *Inspect* indexer as well.  Break this up.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but what is the type of Inspect? I've never done Office stuff in C#, but I've done a bit of raw COM, and ATL COM before C# came along. (which is why I'm curious)

Comment: I made a multi-edit post. I think the solution is below.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] To state the obvious, why don't you call:

```
 inspect.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
```

Since you already have the inspector?

This is what the C++ looks like (incomplete). The type library information shows that get_Inspectors returns a list of Inspectors:

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Inspectors (/*[out,retval]*/ struct _Inspectors * * Inspectors ) = 0;
```

Imported by:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\mso.dll" no_namespace
#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\msoutl.olb" rename_namespace("Outlook")
```

Utilizing the smart wrappers, access looks something like this:

```
_ApplicationPtr app("Outlook.Application");
_InspectorsPtr list = app->GetInspectors();
_InspectorPtr i = list->Item(0);
i->Close(OlInspectorClose::olDiscard);
```

Notice that I'm passing an integer index to the Item function. In the C# wrapper the interface declaration looks like this:

```
    [DispId(282)]
    Inspectors _Application.Inspectors { [DispId(282)] get;
```

The Inspectors implementation's this indexer looks like:

```
    [DispId(0)]
    Inspector this[[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] object Index] { [DispId(0)] get; }
```

Notice that the indexer values is declared an object. Its possible that the interop wrapper allows for an Inspector to be passed in, as well as an int. In fact, that would seem the likely scenario given that the indexer would marshal as an int too. Based on your error, I think that may not be the case.

Comment: I tried inspect.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard), but the same exception still occurs for me. I don't know how assignments work in C# so I tried to close the application's inspector collection to be safe.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have a full project you could put up somewhere? I'm curious to see where the inspector is coming from.

Comment: @Cat - FWIW, when using the indexer (and assuming it worked), you'd just be calling Close on the Inspector object instance you already have.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in a position where I can give code away, but Inspect comes from the line : (MailItem.GetInspector) from a UserControl object that appears within a MailItem Compose window.

the Inspectors_Kill method is called after the email is sent, in order to properly kill the window. This needs to be done because Email Compose windows that handle simple MAPI requests behave oddly and leave behind 'ghost' windows behind after being closed.

also it seems that the error message just changed : {"The item’s properties and methods cannot be used inside this event procedure."}

Comment: @Cat - Ok, I can't do much else. I'm certain that something about the Inspector instance is invalid. You could check the properties on the Inspectors collection and ensure that the inspector you have is valid and part of that collection. Without a decent test case there's no way to pursue it further on my end. The calls to the component are well-known end-points, so I doubt that they're part of the problem.